# Difficulty Accessing HTTP URLs/IP Addresses Due to Browser Redirecting to HTTPS: Seeking Solutions

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, http-headers, http-redirect

Title: Difficulty Accessing HTTP URLs/IP Addresses Due to Browser Redirecting to HTTPS: Seeking Solutions

Detailed Question:

I'm encountering an issue where my browser consistently redirects HTTP URLs, domains, or IP addresses to HTTPS, making it difficult for me to access specific content. Despite attempting various solutions, I haven't been able to resolve the problem. Here's what I've tried so far:

Disabled firewall and adjusted security settings: I turned off my firewall and adjusted security settings to see if they were causing the redirection issue, but this didn't resolve the problem.

Adjusted browser settings:

In Google Chrome, I disabled the options "Always use secure connections" and "Use secure DNS" to prevent automatic redirection to HTTPS, but the issue persisted.
In Mozilla Firefox, I made sure not to enable HTTPS-Only Mode to allow access to HTTP URLs/IP addresses, but this also didn't help.
Attempted about:config solutions: I explored about:config settings in Firefox to see if there were any configurations I could adjust to stop the automatic redirection, but I couldn't find a suitable solution.

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to access HTTP URLs, domains, or IP addresses directly without being redirected to HTTPS.

I'm seeking further assistance to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Any additional suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You could try asking at [su].